# Whats causing this NullPointerException in AWT-EventQueue-0?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, event-dispatch-thread, null-pointer

**The Program:**

> A simple Simulator to learn the very basics of Java. The user can input his own code in a supplied editor, which moves players across a field. This code is executed in a separate thread. Aside from this current issue the program works fine, this error popped out of the blue and did not appear before.

**The Problem:**

> For some reason and in random time intervals the player throws the exception seen below. It does not matter what action the player has performed, as this also shows up after a random time when executing an infinitely repeated single action. This error is thrown every time any action on the field is performed, which means that the console log is getting filled up with the same error message over and over.

**The Code**

This is how the user code is executed, the CompileActionListener calls the JavaCompiler:

> ```
> method = CompileActionListener.getNewActor().getClass().getMethod("main");
> method.invoke(CompileActionListener.getNewActor());
> ```

As far as I'm concerned the other code should not throw said execution (stack tree does not hint towards any of my own classes). Since this is a NPE it *should* be easy to trace back, but because of the lack of references towards my classes and the random time interval I'm clueless.

**The stack trace**

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakSpot(GlyphView.java:799)
> at javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakWeight(GlyphView.java:724)
> at javax.swing.text.FlowView$LogicalView.getPreferredSpan(FlowView.java:733)
> at javax.swing.text.FlowView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(FlowView.java:233)
> at javax.swing.text.ParagraphView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(ParagraphView.java:717)
> at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
> at javax.swing.text.BoxView.getMinimumSpan(BoxView.java:568)
> at javax.swing.text.BoxView.calculateMinorAxisRequirements(BoxView.java:903)
> at javax.swing.text.BoxView.checkRequests(BoxView.java:935)
> at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSpanOnAxis(BoxView.java:343)
> at javax.swing.text.BoxView.layout(BoxView.java:708)
> at javax.swing.text.BoxView.setSize(BoxView.java:397)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.setSize(BasicTextUI.java:1722)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.getPreferredSize(BasicTextUI.java:912)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1659)
> at javax.swing.JEditorPane.getPreferredSize(JEditorPane.java:1332)
> at java.awt.BorderLayout.layoutContainer(BorderLayout.java:821)
> at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1508)
> at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1497)
> at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1693)
> at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
> at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1702)
> at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1628)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:704)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:702)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:701)
> at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1719)
> at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ```

Thank you in forward <3

Comment: Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Strange.  In Java 7 and 8, GlyphView.java line 799 contains `startFrom = breaker.preceding(s.offset + (startFrom - pstart)) + (pstart - s.offset);`, which means either `breaker` or `s` must be null, but methods are invoked on each of those objects just a few lines up.  And neither variable is ever reassigned.  I wonder if the exception is happening inside BreakIterator.preceding and the stack frame was removed by JIT.

Comment: I think it may be a JIT issue in java 8 as reported in here http://kingsfleet.blogspot.com.br/2014/11/but-thats-impossible-or-finding-out.html. The solution proposed by the author is to disable JIT for this particular method using the following command line `javaThing -XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot`.

Comment: @ulix now that is getting really interesting. I added said command and - so far - I haven't gotten any exceptions. Thank you very much! Just like the author you linked said, its nice to have a "dirty" workaround, but until I found another solution this will do

Comment: It appears that this issue has been fixed in JRE 8u60 and 9: see https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8060036 and http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/8u60-bugfixes-2620228.html

Answer (score -3):

You can easily solve your problem with the powerful `try` / `catch`.

Comment: "He traducido el post de Español al Inglés. Por favor, publicarlo en StackOverflow sólo en Inglés." ==> "I've translated your post from Spanish to English. Please, post on StackOverflow in English only.".