# Anyone know what is causing a java GlyphView.getBreakSpot() exception?

Tags: java, swing

I have had three separate customers report exceptions while running our application. The root of the exception is a `NullPointerException` in the `javax.swing.text.GlyphView.getBreakSpot` method.

We have hundreds of people running this application every day. We have not released any modifications to our application. The application is deployed as an Applet or JNLP file.

The problem seems to start with a `JEditorPane()` used in our GUI with a call to `getPreferredSize()`. The content in the `JEditorPane()` is text/html. So I suspect there is a bug in the HTML rendering engine inside `JEditorPane`. We just use the default toolkit, no modifications.

I would imagine that if this is a bug in the latest JRE 1.8.0_45 it could affect many swing applications using HTML inside `JEditorPane`s.

So far 2 reports are from OSX users and one from Windows.

Anyone else seeing this?
Anyone got a solution/workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745661/whats-causing-this-nullpointerexception-in-awt-eventqueue-0

Comment: I see that a "work around" is suggested in that post. It is a command line addition that needs to be used when starting up the application.

-XX:CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot

We will test that for now, but long-term "work around"s do not work.

The post mentions JIT but does not exactly explain the problem. 

Are there Swing elements we can/should avoid? Or a toolkit we can add?

Will disabling whatever the "Work Around" disables mess up something else?

Is there a bug report on this with Oracle? Guess I'll do some more googling...